# Raise Elements of Array to Series of Exponents

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array such as:

```
a = np.arange(9)
>> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

If I want to raise each element to succeeding powers of two, I can do it this way:

```
power_2 = np.power(a,2)
power_4 = np.power(a,4)
```

Then I can combine the arrays by:

```
np.c_[power_2,power_4]
>> array([[   0,    0],
       [   1,    1],
       [   4,   16],
       [   9,   81],
       [  16,  256],
       [  25,  625],
       [  36, 1296],
       [  49, 2401],
       [  64, 4096]])
```

What's an efficient way to do this if I don't know the degree of the even monomial (highest multiple of 2) in advance?

Comment: You can use a loop, and then use `np.power(a, 2**i)`

Comment: Yes, that's true. I was hoping there was a numpy feature ready-built for handling situations like this elegantly, but that will do, thanks.

Comment: There probably is a numpy shortcut, I'm just not much of a numpy expert.

Comment: But you could use `np.array([2**i for i in range(n)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to observe is that x^(2^n) = (...(((x^2)^2)^2)...^2)
meaning that you can compute each column from the previous by taking the square.

If you know the number of columns in advance you can do something like:

```
import functools as ft

a = np.arange(5)
n = 4

out = np.empty((*a.shape,n),a.dtype)
out[:,0] = a

# Note: this works by side-effect!
# The optional second argument of np.square is "out", i.e. an
# array to write the result to (nonetheless the result is also
# returned directly)
ft.reduce(np.square,out.T)

out
# array([[    0,     0,     0,     0],
#        [    1,     1,     1,     1],
#        [    2,     4,    16,   256],
#        [    3,     9,    81,  6561],
#        [    4,    16,   256, 65536]])
```

If the number of columns is not known in advance then the most efficient method is to make a list of columns, append as needed and only in the end use `np.column_stack` or `np.c_` (if using `np.c_` do not forget to cast the list to tuple first).

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward approach is:

```
exponents = [2**n for n in a]
[a**e for e in exponents]
```

This works fine for relatively small numbers, but I see what looks like numerical overflow on the larger numbers. (Although I can compute those high powers just fine using scalars.)

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way I could think of is to not calculate the exponents beforehand. Since your exponents follow a very easy pattern, you can express everything using on list-comprehension.

```py
result = [item**2*index for index,item in enumerate(a)]
```

If you are working with quite large datasets, this will cause some serious overhead. This statement will do all calculations immediately and save all calculated element in one large array. To mitigate this problem, you could you a generator expression, which will generate the data on the fly.

```
result = (item**2*index for index,item in enumerate(a))
```

See [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) for more details.